# jms queue implementation

Tags: jms

Is there a resource on the net or a book that describes how a message queue is actually implemented? Is it just a standaloneJVM that keeps listening for requests and implements some variation of the producer-consumer pattern?
Most tutorials give you the steps on how to use jms...I was looking more for the internal workings of how the queue is implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JMS is just a specification and dictates the functional aspect and a Java API of a Queue but not the specific on how a queue is implemented.

There are multiple vendors providing products that adhere to the JMS spec. and thus many different implementations and inner workings, some of them are opensource such as [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) or [JbossMQ](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/jbossmq). Your best bet for learning the internals is looking at the source code of those projects.